# need help working with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created this javascript which generates a random number ranging from 0-20. What I want to do is create a text field where the user has 4 attempts to guess the generated number. How would I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form><input name="code" id="code" type="text" value="" ></input>
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeid() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
}
</script>
<input type="button" style="font-size:9pt" value="Generate Code" onclick="document.getElementById('code').value = makeid()">
</input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here :) http://jsfiddle.net/r7M4n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a global to track state. However, the security of this is weak, as the user could simply reload the page to circumvent the limit. What you really need to do then is track state on the server side (e.g. database) and then use e.g. an Ajax Call on the browser to do the checking :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function makeid() {
    count++;
    if (count <= 4) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    }
    alert('Out of attempts');
}
</script>
```

**Edit**
Apologies, I've only answered half your question.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var attempts = 0;
        var secretValue = makeid(); // Calculate the secret value once, and don't vary it once page is loaded
        function makeid() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        }
        function checkId(userValue) {
            if (parseInt(userValue) == secretValue) {
                alert('Correct');
            }
            else {
                attempts++;
                if (attempts <= 4) {
                    alert('Wrong - try again');
                }
                else {
                    alert('Out of attempts');
                }
            }
        }
  </script>
```

And then change your click handler to

```
onclick="checkId(document.getElementById('code').value);"
```

Comment: The OP wasn't how to generate only four random numbers, it was how to limit the user to only four attempts at guessing what it is.

Comment: Hmm the user now will have to guess a new number each time

Comment: Thanks - I'm fast asleep - have updated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the generated number into an element that is hidden. Keep a count of the attempts, when the user either gets it right or reaches 4 attempts, show the value and whether or not they guessed correctly. Perhaps also show the number of attempts.

Include a reset button to reset the counter and generate a new hidden value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a text field, why not try using the [prompt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) function? Here's a basic idea for the control flow:

1. Generate your random number and store it in a variable.
2. Create some variable like *correct* and set it to false.
3. Prompt the user for a guess in a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) (with 4 iterations)
4. After each guess, check if the guess matches your stored number. If it is, then [break](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) out of the loop early after setting *correct* to true.
5. Upon exiting the for loop, [alert](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) the user whether they won or lost based on the value of *correct*.